# Symfony config.php 403 error

Tags: apache, symfony, osx-mountain-lion

I've just installed *Symfony2* on my computer which run on mountain lion. When i try to access to localhost it works pretty well : when i type `http://localhost/~myusername/Sites` i've got the expected result.

However, when i type `http://localhost/~myusername/Sites/Symfony/web/config.php`, i've got a 403 error. I checked the permissions of the file *Symfony* but nothing's wrong here.

Someone has an idea about how to deal with it please ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup (pay attention to the `Setting up Permissions` section)

Comment: I've properly entered the following commands :

`rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*`

but nothing changed :(

Comment: And can apache read what's inside your Symfony directory?

Comment: I don't know, is it in `/etc/apache2/myusername.conf` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check that apache is running with your user/group (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf).

   ```
   User myusername
   Group staff
   ```
2. check that the userconfig is correct (/etc/apache2/users/myusername.conf). Should be something like:

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

after that you should be able to acces the page like `http://localhost/~myusername/Symfony/web/config.php`

Sidenote; maybe you need a proper PHP installation, check http://php-osx.liip.ch therefor

Comment: It was the good user/group (root/wheel), but for the userconfig the "FollowSymLinks" was lacking. Well it seems to work pretty for now thanks ! :)